# I'm getting the following error when trying to compile a java program through putty: class, interface, or enum expected

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Been troubleshooting this code for a while, and can't seem to find the cause. Sorry if I'm missing something obvious. I'm relatively new to this:

```java
package com.paypal.bfs.test.employeeserv.api;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class SaleP2 {

    public static void main(String args[])

    {
    final double TAXRATE = 0.06;
    double bookPrice1, bookPrice2, tax, totalSale;
    bookPrice1 = 55.00;
    bookPrice2 = 75.25;
    tax = (bookPrice1 + bookPrice2) * TAXRATE;
    totalSale = bookPrice1 + bookPrice2 + tax;
    DecimalFormat twoDigits = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    System.out.println("CSIS DEPT BOOK SALE");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Book1: " + twoDigits.format(bookPrice1));
    System.out.println("Book2: " + twoDigits.format(bookPrice2));
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Tax: " + twoDigits.format(tax));
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Total Sale: " + twoDigits.format(totalSale));
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(" ~* end *~ ");
    }

}
```

Comment: Please provide the exact command line you are using to compile your program and the error you get from the compiler, also show the directory structure - which help in investigating the issue.

Comment: That error almost always indicates a syntax error. I notice that you don't have any method declaration, just java code. It would have been better if you had included the entire file. Also, the line where the problem started.